# Issue after updating resteasy 3.0.8 NOT FOUND EXCEPTION

Tags: resteasy

after i updated my sample app to resteasy 3.0.8.FINAL the path can't be resolved. Before the update the app was running on resteasy 3.0.6.FINAL without any issues.

I'm using the solution with  the ResteasyBootstrap listener. I checked the [release notes](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY/fixforversion/12323844/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3aversion-summary-panel) for 3.0.7 / 3.0.8 but i couldn't find any big breaking change here.

on github you can find my [sample app](https://github.com/knoma/rest)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We tried going from 3.0.6 to 3.1.1 and saw the same problem (404s for all requests), so I tried just going to 3.0.7... and it was still happening. Looks like something changed at 3.0.7.Final but there's nothing in the release notes that jumps out.